# RequireJS how to map "tippy.js" to path

Tags: typescript, requirejs, amd

My typescript module contains: `import tippy from "tippy.js";` where "tippy.js" is a package installed in node_modules.
Compiling it with `module: "amd"` correctly generates:

```
define(["require", "exports", "tippy.js"], function (require, exports, tippy_js_1) {...
```

At runtime the loading fails because RequireJS tries to load the non-existent file "tippy.js" from the server root instead of looking at the path set in:

```
requirejs.config({paths: {"tippy.js": "../node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy-bundle.umd"}});
```

I tried to play also with the map section without success:

```
    map: {
        "tippy.js": {
            "@popperjs/core": "popper",
            "tippy.js":       "../node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy-bundle.umd"
        },
```

Besides changing package to one with a more normal name, is there anything I could try?
Thanks!
mario

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the power of `packages` section in `requirejs.config({})`. If I define:

```
packages: [{
    name: "tippy.js",
    location: "../node_modules/tippy.js",
    main: "dist/tippy-bundle.umd"
}]
```

the package is loaded without problems.